# Using the C++ GDAL API how do I set the GDAL_DATA path?

Tags: gdal, c++

If I want to change the directory of the GDAL_DATA path or point to a different version of a csv file for EPSG numbers how do I do that using the C++ API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [CPLSetConfigOption](http://gdal.org/doxygen/cpl__conv_8h.html#aa0cd1a68fe4f2fc7874cd2da605c36ce). See the [Config Options](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions) docs.

Comment: Thanks, Luke! if I had any reputation I would upvote your answer