# Link GDAL to consume a WFS

Tags: gdal, wfs, c++

I'm using a WFS that is openly available as a demo from the MapServer web site.

```
http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

And now I want to make a client application that can consume this service in C++ (QT) using the GDAL libraries.

I have compiled GDAL with Xerces and curl as the docs say but apart from that they are not very clear about how to use it for a WFS, I'm sure the functionality is there because it says it supports it but I can't find any WFS specific documentation, so far I have just tried to open a connection and get this error:

```
GDALAllRegister();
const char *pszFilename = NULL;
pszFilename = "http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?";
m_dataset = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen(pszFilename, GA_ReadOnly);

if( m_dataset == NULL )
{
    std::cout << "Dataset is empty" << std::endl;
    exit( 1 );
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR 4: `/vsimem/http_1/file.dat' not recognised as a supported file format.

Dataset is empty
ERROR 4: Failed to create temporary file:/tmp/file.dat
```

I have also tried instead of the URL, an XML document that contains the URL like the docs say this should work.

```
<OGRWFSDataSource>
    <URL>http://path/to/WFS/service[?OPTIONAL_PARAMETER1=VALUE[&amp;OPTIONNAL_PARAMETER2=VALUE]]</URL>
</OGRWFSDataSource>
```

But this just says the file isn't a compatible type, any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GDAL 1.x**

GDAL versions < 2.0 have separate raster (gdal) and vector (ogr) libraries. Don't try to open the WFS vector data with GDAL, use OGR instead. GDAL supports raster data, OGR supports vector.

**GDAL 2+**

The raster and vector drivers are integrated into the gdal library and you use `GDALOpenEx` to open both raster and vector datasets. The ogr library/namespace is still available for backwards compatibility.

Here's a link to the [WFS Driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html) documentation and the [OGR API tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/vector_api_tut.html).

Comment: thanks, iv tried this, i downloaded PS and GCS files (although i dont know what they are/what they are for but it said i needed them and linked GDAL_DATA path to the location they are saved) but now when i run using the OGR functions i get this error and have no idea what it means (same error happens if i run ogrinfo in console) `ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 4326 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?`

Comment: but it does print out all of the data from my wfs though

Comment: @AngryDuck Either set a [GDAL_DATA](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#WhatisGDAL_DATAenvironmentvariable) environment variable before running your program or call [CPLSetConfigOption](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/61596/2856). You don't need to download gdal data files, they're included in the source you built from. There's [more files](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/data) than the ones  you downloaded.

Comment: Hmmm that sucks my data dir for my GDAL source contains just a licence text file?? where are these files meant to be?

Comment: ok got the files from the original download they must have got lost when i compiled all something, all working now no errors thanks!!